# Multer could not upload file to GCP on node.js typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-storage, buffer, multer

I am trying to upload a single file using Multer with `"multipart/form-data"` content type to a bucket of google cloud storage.

I am using `"Multer.memoryStorage()"`and `"@google-cloud/storage"`

```
  try {
    const documentFile = (req as MulterRequest).file;
    const blob = bucket.file(documentFile.originalname);
    console.log(documentFile)
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream()

    blobStream.on("error", (err: any) => {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });

    streamifier.createReadStream(documentFile.buffer.length)
      .on('error', (e: any) => {
        console.log("error")
        console.log(e)
        next(e);
      })
      .pipe(blobStream)
      .on('finish', (res: Response) => {
        console.log("success")
        //res.send('done')
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Upload user document successfully',
          data: documentFile,
        });
      });
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
```

I received an error message of `"The \"chunk\" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type number"` at `const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream()` and the file was not uploaded. Whenever i upload a file, i will receive this error and i do not know where am i do wrong. Does anyone know which steps did i do wrong and hopefully can guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

The `documentFile` is containing the following details:

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '1.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 0b 0c 0c 0b 0f 10 0e 10 0f 16 14 13 13 14 16 22 18 1a 18 ... 19425 more bytes>,
  size: 19475
}
```

Comment: You may refer to this [documentation](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/node-js-upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when trying to upload, this is the way I fix it. [I use this example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/main/samples/streamFileUpload.js) from nodejs-storage to solve this.

```
const filename = `${Date.now()}-${req.file.originalname}`;
const file = bucket.file(filename);

const passthroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();
passthroughStream.write(req.file.buffer);
passthroughStream.end();

async function streamFileUpload() {
    passthroughStream.pipe(file.createWriteStream()).on('finish', () => {
        console.log('uploaded');
    });

    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucket.name}`);
}

streamFileUpload().catch(console.error);
```

Just write the req.file.buffer to solve the error.